# Contradictory unresolved external symbol + unused library altogether with VS2017 and FFMPEG 4

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm having a small c++ project in Windows with FFmpeg 4.0.2. However, I have  weird problem: I'm compiling in x64, having x64 libraries, and having correct link input, but I got the `LNK2019 error` *AND* at the same time "unused libraries" in the linker output `/VERBOSE`:

```
1>Unused libraries:
1>  I:\lib\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64\lib\\avcodec.lib
1>  I:\lib\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64\lib\\avutil.lib
```

I checked manually that lib files are x64. `I:\lib\ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64\lib\` is in the LIBPATH.

Same symptoms with ICC.

How could this happen ?

Comment: Could this be due to the double backslashes in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the headers of ffmpeg in a C++ program you have to take in account that ffmpeg uses the C calling conventions. Otherwise your linker will expect C++ name mangling on the function names. However, since ffmpeg is straight C, you'll have to tell you compiler this.
For example if you include `avformat.h` in your program do it as follows.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    #include <avformat.h>
    #include <avcodec.h>
    #include <avutil.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The same goes for the other ffmpeg headers.

Comment: Shouldn't be there two `#ifdef#endif`, one for the opening `{` and one for the closing `}` instead ?

Comment: @Scheff @solei, your both right, There should be two #`ifdef` `#endif` pairs. Fixed that in the answer.